# System.Globalization.CultureInfo does not contain a definition for Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this peculiar issue with the System.Globalization.CultureInfo class and the System.Globalization namespace. I'm returning an object (Languages) from an API call that has a CultureInfo property. I'm able to successfully pull this on the client side into an `IENumerable<Language> languages {get; set;}` but when I try to build with a line such as `var x = model.languages.First().AssociatedCulture.Name` I'm met with the following errors:

Error   489 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'EnglishName' and no extension method 'EnglishName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   488 The type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Here is the sequence of lines I have run to try this out:

```
var y = new CultureInfo("en"); //works
var z = y.Name; //works
var x = model.languages.First().AssociatedCulture.EnglishName; //error at this line.
```

I don't understand this phantom error. If it helps, the project that creates Language.cs uses the .NET portable v.4.5.

I have tried adding this to the web.config assemblies block but no dice.

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Globalization , Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Is it somehow caused by .NET portable?

Comment: The MSDN docs say that .NET Portable supports this.  Have you added a reference to `System.Globalization` to the project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a *project reference* to `System.Globalization`.

When you edit the `web.config` file you're adding a reference for the dynamic assembly that's generated from your `.aspx`/`.cshtml` files, this is separate and distinct from your project references (which are references for the output DLL from your project).

Add a Project Reference in Visual Studio via Solution Explorer.