# BC30456: CultureInfo is not a member of Globalization

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, reference, windows-10

I started getting the following error on an ASPX project in VS2015, suddenly out of the blue, seemingly after Windows 10 installed `Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607`:

> BC30456: 'CultureInfo' is not a member of 'Globalization'.

This is occurring in a server-side code file that had no problem before. I use git to track changes, and the only thing that changed in the whole project was moving a comment from one place to another (I even tried undoing the change). Aside from that, this is my first time opening the project since Windows installed the version 1607 update, if that has anything to do with it. Specifically, I was using the project the previous day.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269311/system-globalization-cultureinfo-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-name), which suggests adding a reference to `System.Globalization` for the project. I tried adding a reference to `System.Globalization` specifically, but there was no such entry to be found. I then tried adding a reference to `mscorlib` (both via the listed entry and via file browse), and it said `mscorlib` was already referenced. Also, in the source code the line using `Globalization.CultureInfo` appears just fine without any red markings. Mousing over shows information for the components, and `Go to definition` browses to a place in `mscorlib` where the `CultureInfo` class is defined.

The problem is when selecting `View in Browser`. This is a non-compiled project (no bin), although I did try `Rebuild Solution`, which made no difference in the error condition. I uploaded the code file in this exact state to the server, and it runs just fine on the actual server.

**Update 1**: I tried adding a reference in `Web.Config` as follows, but **this did not resolve the issue**:

> ```
> <compilation>
>   <assemblies>
>     <add assembly="System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
>   </assemblies>
> </compilation>
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Although I cannot say exactly what was being referenced instead, apparently when I said `Globalization.CultureInfo` **it was referencing a different "Globalization"**. Simply adding `System` to the front made the error go away. This is very peculiar. I tried searching the solution for `Globalization`, but nothing else came up. I have no idea why this started at this point since nothing in the project had changed, since the actual server does not require `System` to be prefixed, and since mouse-over info does not seem to care. Again, the solution is as follows:

> **System**.Globalization.CultureInfo... // Try including "System." at the front.

Answer (score 1):

On your code, you need to change this:

`Globalization.DateTimeStyles`

For this:

`System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The compiler was getting the error:

BC30456: 'DateTimeStyles' is not a member of 'Globalization'.

I just installed Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2013. The OS installed an update and now is running the .Net Framework release: 4.6.1586.0.
Your solution solved my problem:
including System before globalization:

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles
```

The strange thing is that before the upgrade to Win10 + .Net 4.6, I was using the same code without the need of specifing "System.".